# I am having trouble 'syncing' my files

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync

First, I love ubuntu...thank you...you folks are brilliant!  The problem I'm having is when I 'right-click' to sync my files the only option I am given is 'Hide Ribbon' ...I just want to sync my files, but I am not given the option?  T/Y for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Which files are you trying to sync?

Ubuntu One syncs everything inside the “Ubuntu One” folder in your home, as well as any *folders* on which you right click and select “synchronize this folder”:

[image: Ubuntu One options for a folder]

We're not currently able to offer syncing of individual files:

[image: Ubuntu One options for an unsync'ed file]